# sharepoint 2010 ecmascript user profile property

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

There is a user profile property named "EmployeeID" for every user. I would like to retreive the current user's "EmployeeID" using emcascript but can't figure out how to.

```
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");
        var context = null;
        var web = null;
        var currentUser = null;

        function getWebUserData() {      
            context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            web = context.get_web();
            currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
            currentUser.retrieve();
            context.load(web);
            context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
        }
        function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
            var currentUser= web.get_currentUser();
// how to get employeeID user profile property?

        }
        function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
            alert('Unable to find your user information.');
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the user profile properties using CSOM. Go and check out SPServices and the implementation of the GetUserProfileNNN methods: http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UserProfileService&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices